# powershell iterating through a large file

Tags: powershell, large-files, powershell-4.0, loops

Hello I just started powershell and I am working with a powershell script that is to iterate through a large file holding lines such as "ABCD#######";"####";"@@";##;"@@";####;#####;"@";. What i need to do in powershell is iterate through this file which can contain more than 20,000 lines and grab parts of the information from each line and output it to another file. I have that working, problem is it is really slow and was wondering if someone could help here's my code.

```
foreach ($fileName in (ls i.gft1* | %{$_.name})){   
$fileNo=1
$STUFFCount=0
cd work
new-item flttemp$fileNo -type file -force
cat $fileName | %{$_.replace('"','')} > temp 

foreach ($line in (cat temp)){
    echo $containerCount

    if ($STUFFCount -eq 999)
    {
        $fileNo=$fileNo+1
        $STUFFCount=0
        break;
        new-item flttemp$fileNo -type file
    }
    add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_START" -encoding utf8
    add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF"-encoding utf8
    $no=$line.split(";")[0]
    if ($line.substring("3","1") -eq "U")
    {
        add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_TYPE:STUFF" -encoding utf8
    }
    else
    {
        add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_TYPE:STUFF" -encoding utf8
    }
    add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_NO:$no" -encoding utf8
    add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_NOTO:$no" -encoding utf8
    $ISO=$line.split(";")[1]
    add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_ISO:$ISO" -encoding utf8
    $weight=$line.split(";")[5]
    if ($weight -gt 0)
    {
        $weight=2.20462 * $weight
        $weight=$weight.tostring("#.##")
        add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_WGT:$weight" -encoding utf8
    }
    else
    {
        add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_WGT:" -encoding utf8
    }
    $weight=$line.split(";")[6]
    if ($weight -gt 0)
    {
        $weight=2.20462 * $weight
        $weight=$weight.tostring("#.##")
        add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_MWGT:$weight" -encoding utf8
    }
    else
    {
        add-content flttemp$fileNo "STUFF_MWGT:" -encoding utf8
    }
    add-content flttemp$fileNo "}STUFF_END" -encoding utf8
    $STUFFCount=$STUFFCount+1
}
```

}

The code works (if the editing didn't miss anything) its just that the kornshell version of this completes the flttemp$fileNo files in 1 minute while it takes powershell 4-5 minutes, which is too slow for how many files this script needs to go through. My question again is, is there a way i'm not using to optimize powershell to read through files faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reading each file completely into memory and then working on that. This will certainly speed up things when dealing with large files

```
foreach ($fileName in (ls i.gft1* | %{$_.name}))
{
    $fileString = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filename")  # gives you one string containing whole file

    # or

    $lines = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines("$filename")   # gives a collection of strings (lines)   

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        # $line is a line (string)
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new to this so i don't know how i would loop the $lines in powershell.

Comment: Thanks, it is an improvement of 30 seconds, but still a bit too slow for what i need. Powershell i guess is a bit too slow for iterating through big files. I'll look into ReadAllText and see if i can do something with that.

Comment: You are probably doing loads more file IO work in the code that doesnt need to be there. Ideally, you would load file into memory, add the data you want to keep to a string or collection in memory, then when you are done - write this thing to file once. Minimising calls to disk as much as possible will always speed things up.

Comment: So writing the output out in 1 string with new lines once would probably improve the time correct?

Comment: Certainly. At the moment you are appending each line that you want to a file using add-content and this happens every iteration. Its going to be slow. You can just add to a string that has already been declared outside of the loop. like - $string += $contenttoadd (or $string += $contenttoadd + "`n" if you need new lines). Then you can use [IO.File]::WriteAllText() to write that string to a file.

Comment: thank you, i did something similar and had one add-content and it went from 4 minutes to 6 seconds for each flttemp iteration